# Escrever TXT formatado através do VB6

Tags: tabela-html, visual-basic-6

Estou tentanto copiar a estrutura de um GRID/Tabela dentro de um arquivo texto, copiando inclusive a estrutura das celulas(Tabela).

Porém, eu nao consigo alinhar as colunas no arquivo texto, apesar de possuir um tamanho padrão para cada coluna.

O processo funciona da seguinte maneira, eu meço o maior item contido em cada linha de cada columa e entao uso seu tamanho para definir o espaço total da coluna em questão. Quando o texto é menor que o tamanho total da coluna, eu preencho os caracteres restantes com espaço em branco.

O que notei, que é as letras saem de tamanhos variados e minha medida é dada pelo número de caracteres. No entanto, o espaço que a letra "A" ocupa, é diferente do espaço ocupado pela letra "T" por exemplo.

Eu tentei escolher alguma fonte true-tipe no bloco de notas(Tahoma,Arial,Impact) mas mesmo assim as letras parecem ter tamanho diferente no bloco de notas.

Sabem me dizer como poderia construir uma tabela, de tamanho padronizado, escrita no bloco de notas!? Considerando por exemplo, que a unidade de medida é o tamanho do caractere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema não está no seu programa que gera o arquivo texto (VB6) e sim na visualização do arquivo, pois se o programa usado (ex: bloco de notas) estiver usando um fonte de espaçamento variável (ex: arial) o conteúdo ficará embaralhado.

Você não tem que usar fontes true-type e sim fontes de espaçamento fixo, como por exemplo: courier new.

Comment: Ao utilizar courier new, todo o alinhamento ficou perfeito.